# Form property returning undefined when rendered

Tags: reactjs

I using a prop to render errors that should only fire when an error is returned to the form after the submit button has been clicked. This functionality is working however when the form loads I'm geting a console error `Cannot read property 'company' of undefined`.

Path: `SingleInput props`

```
const SingleInput = (props) => (
  <FormGroup validationState={props.error ? 'error' : null}>
    {props.error ? <HelpBlock>{props.error}</HelpBlock> : '' }
  </FormGroup>
);
SingleInput.propTypes = {
  error: PropTypes.string
};
```

Path: `form`

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    careerHistoryPositions: [{company: '', errors: {} }],
  };
}

render() {
  return (
    {this.state.careerHistoryPositions.map((careerHistoryPosition) => (
      <div key={careerHistoryPosition.uniqueId} className="individual-position">
        <SingleInput
          error={careerHistoryPosition.errors['company']}
        />
      </div>
    ))}
  )
}
```

Comment: I see two mistaked, you need to wrap your map function within a div since you can only return one element from render, and `key={careerHistoryPosition.uniqueId} ` is a problem since `uniqueId` is not defined in the object

Comment: I have a lot of code. Those two things are in my full markup. The error I'm getting is directly related to `error={careerHistoryPosition.errors['company']}` I've tried things like `error={!!careerHistoryPosition.errors['company']}` and that doesn't work either. My confusion is coming from the fact, it should be `undefined` when it first renders as there is no error at that point. It only returns an error if there is one when the form is submitted.

Comment: Can you log carrerHistoryPostion object within the map

Comment: It can't be that if there is stored data in the database the form populates. So careerHistoryPositions is working correctly. Is it something to do with errors being an empty array in the constructor. Should that be different?

Comment: So the error was related to my constructor. I needed to define `company` within the errors. The fix was simple, `careerHistoryPositions: [{company: '', errors: {company: '' } }],`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here. **careerHistoryPosition.errors['company']**

**careerHistoryPosition** is an array and you are writing **careerHistoryPosition.errors** which will be undefined as you are trying to get a key from an array. Then you are trying get the value of company from undefined.

Comment: Where has the OP mentioned that `careerHistoryPostion` is an array. I think you are mistaking it with `careerHistoryPostions`

Comment: But by looking at the error, `can not read property company of undefined`, I think that may be a typo in render.